# sorting large amounts of urls by top domain in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, url, count

a mysql database i'm working with has thousands of urls. now, a lot of those urls will be from the same domain, but each one will have differing sub-domains and page names. e.g.

```
somewebsite.com/gj29sjw  
somewebsite.com/29shw0a  
somewebsite.com/92jslwa

anothersite.net/jfdkden   
anothersite.net/hj2892j  
anothersite.net/282j290
```

etc...

Is there a query or syntax I can use to both group those urls and count them in largest first order, without the subdomains and page names. Ideally, after i run the count query, I would need to get:

```
somewebiste.com | 345 
anothersite.net | 289
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to make the query fairly simple; just take the 2 last period separated groups before the first slash;

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 1), '.', -2) site, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM mytable
GROUP BY site;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e69ba1/2).

Note that to get *good* performance on the query, I'd recommend storing the site name separately, doing calculations on each ro will not give ultimate performance.

Comment: i fixed the above problem by changing it to (url, '/', 3), however, i get a tone of rows with teh same domain name and a '1' next to them in the comment field

Comment: @bobby What exactly is your query? Are you grouping by site like the answer above?

Comment: yes, i'm using your query above, just changed (url, '/', 1) to url, '/', 3)

Comment: @bobby [Can't repeat](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbfc41/1). Could you add some sample data that generates that effect?

Comment: got it to work, you were right, my bad with the query

Answer (score 0):

```
select substr(url, 1, instr(url, '/') - 1) as domain_name, count(*) as cnt
from your_table
group by domain_name
order by cnt desc
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/39757)

Answer (score 0):

juergen d, your group by is wrong.

```
select substr(url, 1, instr(url, '/') - 1), count(*) as cnt
from your_table
group by substr(url, 1, instr(url, '/') - 1)
order by cnt desc
```

Comment: thanks, i've tried that, but get two rows one just reads (http:) and the other (https:) each one has a row next to it with the amount of rows in the table with that protocol. I'm trying to move the forward slash, but can't seem to get it right

Comment: use: **`instr(url, '.com')+3`** instead of **`instr(url, '/') -1`**